# Font formatting and or condition

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, formatting, conditional-statements

I have a data-set for a table with 10 different currencies with value attached.
The font color for the values have to be changed to RAG (Red, Amber, Green) condition for every currency specific.
I've tried to rebuild several VBA examples with CASE, IF AND OR etc.

Retrieved data and requirements.
[image]

Comment: Set the conditions in Excel while recording a macro. That should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Well i had no luck with the recorder
I gave it a rest some days and came up with the following
Whenever i change the value of D4 the color of E4 changes

```
If Range("D4") > 60 And Range("C4") = "RUB" Then
    Range("E4").Interior.color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
ElseIf (Range("D4") > 30 And Range("D4") < 60) And Range("C4") = "RUB" Then
    Range("E4").Interior.color = RGB(225, 192, 0)
ElseIf Range("D4") < 30 And Range("C4") = "RUB" Then
    Range("E4").Interior.color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
ElseIf Range("D4") > 60 And Range("C4") = "USD" Then
    Range("E4").Interior.color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
ElseIf (Range("D4") > 30 And Range("D4") < 60) And Range("C4") = "USD" Then
    Range("E4").Interior.color = RGB(225, 192, 0)
ElseIf Range("D4") < 30 And Range("C4") = "USD" Then
    Range("E4").Interior.color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
Else
    Range("E4").Interior.color = RGB(1, 111, 44)
End If
```

I managed to have this run automatically on the sheet
Now only wondering if this can be simplified